# How to get same date, start time and end time form database where date my have multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image: image one]

I want Query in PHP Mysql.

I want to get result like if session_Date is same then it shows like
2021-04-02 only one time and session_start time will be first time means 09:30 and last time means 12:30

that means session_date will display only one time and times will display start time and end time.

so I want below formate

```
session_date | session_start_time | session_end_time
2021-04-02 | 09:30 | 12:30
2021-04-03 | 09:30 | 10:30
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT
 session_date,
 MIN(session_start_time),
 MAX(session_end_time)
FROM session
GROUP BY session_date
```

**UPDATE:**

For your case, you could do the following:

```
SELECT
  session_date,
  TIME_FORMAT(MIN(STR_TO_DATE(session_start_time, '%h:%i %p')), '%h:%i %p'),
  TIME_FORMAT(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(session_end_time, '%h:%i %p')), '%h:%i %p')
FROM session 
GROUP BY session_date;
```

But I would suggest you store date and time in fields with the respective types, that is `session_date` as `DATE` and `session_start_time` and `session_end_time` as `TIME` type.

Comment: what about time in AM or PM. I have tried your query with multiple same two dates like below data

Please try with given data

2021-04-02 | 09:30 AM |10:30 AM

2021-04-03 | 09:30 AM | 0:30 AM

2021-04-02 | 11:30 AM | 12:30 PM

2021-04-03 | 01:30 PM | 02:30 PM

Comment: Thanks. It's Working Fine with multiple dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to group the values. If using eloquent and assuming your model is sessions:

```php
Session::groupBy('session_date')->get();
```